# Equality of Double Limits of Sequence of Real Numbers

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a_{mn}$ be a set of real numbers indexed by $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$. Is there an example of such a set $a_{mn}$ where

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{m \to \infty} a_{nm} \neq \lim_{m \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{nm}
$$

or are these two limits always equal?

Answer (score 1):

Set $$a_{n,m}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1 & n>m\\ 0 & n\le m\end{array}\right.$$

Then

$$0=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} a_{n,m} \not= \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_{n,m} = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

Take $a_{nm} = \dfrac{n+m}{n-m}$, see for yourself the limits aren't the same. One is $-1$ and the other is $1$.